# LASTPAYMENTDATE is often not present in GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails API Operation (NVP)

Tags: paypal

I've been testing some calls to GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails, and am trying to understand the behaviour of LASTPAYMENTDATE. I require this field because I want to differentiate between times where no payment has yet to be made and one has.

There seems to be some odd behaviour, though. I cancelled a payment profile, which happened successfully, and then called GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails, but no LASTPAYMENTDATE was present. I called it again and received a 500, and then again and LASTPAYMENTDATE was present. Each call after that (for this particular profile) has not returned any LASTPAYMENTDATE (although the payment is visible in the merchant account if I log in to the UI).

I think I'm going to switch to using the NUMCYCLESCOMPLETED field for my purpose instead, but any ideas why I'm seeing strange behaviour for LASTPAYMENTDATE? Is it a bug? Anyone else noticed this?

Many thanks.

Update: The same profile is now returning LASTPAYMENTDATE.

Update: It's stopped coming back again.